# 3 years back or ago?

Tags: grammar

Is it acceptable to use *back* in place of *ago* ?

example :

> They met around three years back

or

> They met around three years ago

I saw the former being used in a reputed Indian daily today.

Comment: In my opinion , the second is certainly the way to go,  because i have never seen or heard of,  the first usage. But,  the first one does not seem all that bad.

Comment: In case of any suspense, the newspaper was the Times of India.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/back_1) does not mark this sub-sense of *back* as informal or colloquial:

> **back** [adverb (5)]: used for talking about a period of time in the past
>
> *Back in the ’70s, disco music was very popular.*
>
> ***She had a minor operation a few years back.***
>
> *Things were different back then.*

[bolding mine]

However, people on various other websites {eg massromantic at [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-few-years-back-informal.1713955/)} consider 'three years back' less formal than 'three years ago', and I'd agree with them, especially for British usage:

> "Yes, I think it ['a few years back'] is slightly more informal. I
>   don't see it written often -- I usually just hear people say it."

Comment: I agree with you - though it is heavily used in Britain. (Sometimes, from stray comments like this think it will not be understood once they set foot on the ground at Heathrow.)

Comment: I totally with you, they're not only more formal but more idiomatic as well, plus I've never heard someone ​saying  "years back"+1

Comment: I had to check data, but you appear to be correct if you mean 'more commonly used' by 'more idiomatic'.

Comment: Definitely agree on British usage - "Back" would be relatively informal, although regularly heard in all usages by middle aged Northerners. I've definitely heard "years back", both in "Years back, when I met your mother". or "They met three years back" contexts